# Gerrit authentication: how to disable anonymous user

Tags: gerrit

How can i stop anonymous user to view my project activities in gerrit. I have googled enough but could'nt find what are exact files which are called Access Control List for project.

Comment: Is it only about your personal activity or about any changes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to disallow anonymous users to browse/read/search all the changes of a certain project, you just have to remove the [Read](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_read) permission for anonymous users from the project.

In order to be allowed to modify permissions, you have to be either Administrator or owner of that project.

To disallow anonymous browsing, follow these steps:

- Go to *Projects* > *List* in the menu
- Click on the project's name (or *All-Projects*, if you want to modify the default for all projects (requires being Administrator))
- Choose *Access* in the submenu and hit the *Edit* button there.
- From *Reference: refs/** remove in the *Read* section the *ALLOW Anonymous Users* using the *X* on the right side.
- Hit *Save changes*