# How to setup Gerrit without any authentication?

Tags: gerrit

I downloaded Gerrit, unpacked it and started the server with `bin/gerrit.sh start`. Then I noticed that I cannot log into the web frontend and looked for my options. Since all I would like to do is add a test project and play around with it to explore the features, I would actually like to avoid authentication at all.

Is there a way to get this going without openid or ldap. `auth.type=http` would be just right, but this again requires an apache in front. Or can I just configure jetty to do it. If so, how?

Comment: You can specify the project specific settings. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241341/gerrit-authentication-how-to-disable-anonymous-user). This will help you with the configurations.